# Windows Routing Table

Tags: windows, networking, routing

Consider following routing entries in windows route table:

```
Address     Mask             Gateway    Interface   Metric:
0.0.0.0     0.0.0.0          10.0.43.1  10.0.43.6   10
127.0.0.1   255.255.255.255  On-link    127.0.0.1   20
```

If I connect to 127.0.0.1 why does it choose to loopback? Metric to network 0.0.0.0 is lower, hence it should choose to use 10.0.43.1, isn't it? How does windows choose a path?

Comment: Because localhost and 127.0.0.1 is a **hardcoded** exception in windows. Try a ping to localhost, even without DNS/host entries and without routing. It should fail, but instead it is intercepted at an early stage and works. I *guess* this was done to optimize performance and to get to a safe state even without any NICs, but to be sure you would need to ask in Redmond.  (Note that this is not windows specific. E.g. linux network code also starts with lo0 as a hardcoded device).

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is the local loopback interface. Therefore just as if you entered the interface IP of your machine (10.0.43.6) it will route directly without using the gateway. This rule is part of IP protocol and is true for any device.

It is also worth noting that the default gateway is only used if the destination IP is not immediately available on one of the interfaces. For instance if you were to connect to 10.0.43.7 (which is on the same subnet as your IP) it would connect directly rather than using a gateway.

Comment: So whenever I try to connect to any ip, my computer will try all possible routes to check if node is immediately available?

Comment: No. If you connect to an IP that is on your local network it already knows its there, and it won't even consider that it could be anywhere else.
It knows your IP and it knows the size of the range (from the subnet mask) so it knows every IP that should be on your network, if it tries to transmit to it and doesn't get a response it just assumes the device is off but it knows it should be on your local network segment so wont look anywhere else.
Loopback (127.0.0.1) is slightly different because it always knows that means the local machine.